# How many isosceles, right-angled, INSCRIBED triangles exist in an ellipse?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Are there more than four **isosceles, right-angled, INSCRIBED triangles** in an ellipse? 
By inscribed, I mean all three vertexes should lie ON the ellipse.

I am attaching a simplified picture that shows my count of four such triangle. 
Two of them form the only inscribed square of an ellipse in the middle. 
The other two would exist at each end.

Are there any proof or studies showing that these are the only four, or are there more?

*Edit: As Deepak pointed, when I said four, I was not careful. If you draw the diagonal line in the inscribed square the other way, you can also have two others.

To give you a better idea, I'm specifically wondering whether there are isosceles right angled inscribed triangles at different locations entirely, as is shown in my supplementary diagram that has a question mark.

Note that in that diagram, I'm using a FAKE isosceles triangle (the two sides are not actually of same lengths), as I cannot find a true isosceles triangle. But I'm wondering whether a real one exists that looks similar to what is drawn.[image]

[image]

Comment: Is "isolateral" the same thing as isosceles?

Comment: Thanks Deepak, that was my mistake, isosceles is the right term and that's what I meant.

Comment: Also, your largest pair of triangles form a square, where the dividing diagonal can be drawn another way generating another pair of triangles. Trivial, but you must state clearly what you're looking for: what's the max number of inscribed isosceles right triangles that can be drawn without any vertex of one triangle being allowed as a vertex of another, and is overlapping allowed, etc.? (When you have an ellipse with a lower eccentricity, I think you will have area overlap between small and large triangles).

Comment: oh fair point!! That does not matter so much to what I'm seeking, but I see I was not being clear. I will edit it in a moment

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Yes, of course, if I can elongate or shrink a bit, I could easily see it would restore the fit into the ellipse. How would have helped me intuitively decide whether there are other isosceles right angled triangles, though?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer I thought you meant elongating or shrinking each side differently. If you meant at the same ratio, then ok. But still, intuitively that was not possible to decide.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider the following diagram.

[image]

Here $D$ is an arbitrary but fixed point on the ellipse, without loss of generality in the first quadrant. $E$ and $G$ are variable points counterclockwise of $D$, and $E'$ and $G'$ are their $90^\circ$ rotations. $DEE'$ and $DGG'$ are then isosceles right-angled triangles. We find the following:

- When the second point is close to $D$, as with $E$, then its rotation ($E'$) lies inside the ellipse.
- When the second point is far from $D$, as with $G$, then its rotation ($G'$) lies outside the ellipse.

So, since motions are continuous, there must be a position for the second point where the third point lies exactly *on* the ellipse, making an inscribed triangle. Hence there are infinitely many right-angled isosceles triangles inscribed in the ellipse.

[image]

---

As Misha Lavrov says, the exact position for $E$ can be found by rotating the ellipse $90^\circ$ around $D$. $E$ is another ellipse intersection (there may be up to three of them):

[image]

Comment: One way to think about finding the position for the second point is to rotate *the ellipse* $90^\circ$ about $D$, and find the second intersection point of the original ellipse and the rotated ellipse. That intersection point will be $E'$, and its preimage will be $E$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Good catch. I've added another picture in to illustrate that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Infinitely many... I see I was off by quite a few triangles. @Misha Lavrov or Parcly Taxel, Can you please explain why rotating the ellipse leads to this finding? Let’s say we find the second point-the one intersecting the rotated ellipse. How does it follow that it is an isosceles?

Comment: @SK Because we only rotated the ellipse around $D$.

Comment: @SK: For any candidate right triangle vertex on the ellipse, you can find where the other vertex would be by rotating the candidate vertex 90 degrees around D. If you rotate *every* candidate vertex 90 degrees around D, that's rotating the whole ellipse 90 degrees around D. The intersections correspond to candidates that are still on the ellipse when rotated.